# Magento Translation of Text Contained in Javascript File

Tags: javascript, magento, translation

I have a module that displays some text in JavaScript like below:

```
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#contact-container .contact-loading').fadeOut(200, function () {
                                $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Thank you!');
                                msg.html(data).fadeIn(200);
                            });
                        },
```

How would I go about adding this text into my translation file?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Magento's translation system can't govern Javascript files (as it should).

One way to handle this is to use the default skin folder to store CSS and JS so your different stoer views fall back to this folder and you would make all your CSS changes in the default folder. Then for example, with the German store view, specify the `Skin (Images / CSS)` folder under `System >> Config >> Design` to eg. `german`

**What we essentially have is a fallback system**  and you can upload a German Javascript file into that folder and likewise with the other store views in different languages.

All your other assets that do not need to be different per store sits under the default folder so they do not need to be uploaded x number of times where x is your number of stores.

Hope this makes sense, let me know if it doesn't!

Comment: Yes, I see what your saying as I figured out a little hack that's similar to what your saying but not as good. The JS file was not in a theme but in the root js folder so I copied it and gave it a new name (contact-es.js) then in the XML layout for that language I added the new file name. It works.

Comment: @Freejoy yes that is another good way to do it. You could also edit head.phtml and make it echo the store ID in the `<body class="...` and use an if statement in the JS itself.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to either generate this document with PHP (and pass it through Magento's translation  facility), or reference a variable in your JS which you generate elsewhere via PHP.

This is similar to the BLANK_URL and BLANK_IMG variables which are set in ***app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml***:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var BLANK_URL = '<?php echo $this->getJsUrl() ?>blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = '<?php echo $this->getJsUrl() ?>spacer.gif';
    var BASE_URL = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*') ?>';
    var SKIN_URL = '<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl() ?>';
    var FORM_KEY = '<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>';
</script>
```

In fact, it would be possible to declare and translate this script in layout XML. The other option would be translated versions which rely on the theming fallback - I tend to prefer DRY, especially when translation is the only difference.

Comment: Thanks your reply is right on too. I'm glad you mentioned this little piece of code: <?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?> I think I needed that. :)